# Extracting data from an html response in python

Tags: python, parsing, extract

as a response of a request, i'm getting a full 1600 lines html document.

what i'm trying to do is find a way to extract a value from a specific line:

```
    <input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" data-parsley-errors-container="#form__token_error" value="tHV9QvBk9HEvZSP8S8bCkpC1vsSE4B4HthgXgk4V7FM" /></form>
```

at line 1594 of my document, i'm trying to get the value of `value`. What i thought of doing was to do extract the tag `value` and its value to then delete everything that was not that but the tag does appear elsewhere in my html file so there is no point.

any ideas on how i could make this work ?
thank you for your help and time !

Comment: You could use BeautifulSoup to parse the html and then extract the value you need. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need 'request' and 'BeautifulSoup' for getting the data you want from the said url

Try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = ('link to url')

page = requests.get(url, timeout = 5) #timeout only if required
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser') 

value = soup.find(id='form__token')

print(value)
```

Comment: Yes thank you, gives me the right line. Now i can only keep what i need !